# ag-grid copy option not working when we enable row selection to multiple

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2, ag-grid-angular

AG-Grig context menu default option copy (cntl+c) not copying the selected rows, when row selection of gridOptions.rowSelection = 'multiple', how can we override the copy option to copy the entire row?

It is working for single row, when we select multiple rows, copying cells instead of copying rows? How can we get both behaviours?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where the browser (specifically IE11) was denied programmatic clipboard access:

[image]